# How to store DNS output in a variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, networking, dns

How do I store the return value of dns.lookup in a variable? If I store it in an array it shows blank.

Following is the code I'm working on:

```
    const dns = require('dns');
    class Network
    {
        search(host)
        {
            let options = {
                hints: dns.ADDRCONFIG | dns.V4MAPPED,
                all: true,
                verbatim: true
           }

           let addr = [];
           dns.lookup(host, options, (error, address) =>
               {
                   if(error)
                   {
                       console.log("Could not resolve %s\n", host);
                       console.log(error);
                   }
                   address.forEach(ip => {
                       addr.push({
                           address: ip.address,
                           family: ip.family
                       });
                   });
               });
           console.log(addr);
           return addr;
       }
   }   

   const network = new Network();
   let output = network.search("www.google.com");
   console.log(output);
```

The output of the code is Blank i.e. []

Please suggest a rememdy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax along with the very useful [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function.

This gives us code that is more compact, it will also allow you to write your code in a way that's very similar to synchronous code.

We'll then use some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pick only the properties in the address object(s) we're interested in.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;

class Network
{
    async search(host)
    {
        let options = {
            hints: dns.ADDRCONFIG | dns.VMAPPED,
            all: true,
            verbatim: true
        }

        let address = await promisify(dns.lookup)(host, options);       
        return address.map( ({address, family}) => {
            return { address, family };
        });
    }
}   

async function testSearch() {
    const network = new Network();
    let output = await network.search("www.google.com");
    console.log(output);
}

testSearch();
```

Comment: Never tried promisify earlier, it looks like a very powerful tool and the code looks much cleaner now. Thanks Terry, appreciate it.

Comment: It's very useful for sure, happy coding! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter to `dns.lookup` must be a callback as you have already noticed. The method is asynchronous but this line `return addr;` is not - addr is returned before getting populated.
The method definition of `search` could be changed to take as second parameter a callback that will be called with the result of `dns.lookup`.
Something like this:

```
search(host, done) {
...
  dns.lookup(host, options, (err, addresses) => {
    ...
    const finalAddresses = [];
    addresses.forEach((ip) => {
      finalAddresses.push({
        address: ip.address,
        family: ip.family
      });
    });

    done(null, finalAddresses);
  });
}

const network = new Network();
network.search("www.google.com", (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log(result);
});
```